# Mac to Windows Python

Tags: python

I have recently moved a set of near identical programs from my mac to my school's windows, and while the paths appear to be the same (or the tail end of them), they will not run properly.

```
import glob
import pylab
from pylab import *


def main():
    outfnam = "igdata.csv"
    fpout = open(outfnam, "w")
    nrows = 0
    nprocessed = 0
    nbadread = 0
    filenames = [s.split("/")[1] for s in glob.glob("c/Cmos6_*.IG")]
    dirnames = "c an0 an1 an2 an3 an4".split()
    for suffix in filenames:
        nrows += 1
        row = []
        row.append(suffix)
        for dirnam in dirnames:
            fnam = dirnam+"/"+suffix
            lines = [l.strip() for l in open(fnam).readlines()]
            nprocessed += 1
            if len(lines)<5:
                nbadread += 1
                print "warning: file %s contains only %d lines"%(fnam, len(lines))
                tdate = "N/A"
                irrad = dirnam
                Ig_zeroVds_largeVgs = 0.0
            else:
                data = loadtxt(fnam, skiprows=5)
                tdate = lines[0].split(":")[1].strip()
                irrad = lines[3].split(":")[1].strip()
                # pull out last column (column "-1") from second-to-last row
                Ig_zeroVds_largeVgs = data[-2,-1]
            row.append(irrad)
            row.append("%.3e"%(Ig_zeroVds_largeVgs))
        fpout.write(", ".join(row) + "\n")
    print "wrote %d rows to %s"%(nrows, outfnam)
    print "processed %d input files, of which %d had missing data"%( \
        nprocessed, nbadread)`
```

This program worked fine for a mac, but for windows I keep getting for :

```
 print "wrote %d rows to %s"%(nrows, outfnam)
    print "processed %d input files, of which %d had missing data"%( \
        nprocessed, nbadread)
```

wrote 0 row to file name
processed 0 input files, of which o had missing data

on my mac i go 144 row to file...

does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces to have it show up as code. No one will bother trying to read through it until you do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, It says I cannot fix this for at least 8 hours...

Comment: Strangely, I cannot edit this post either.

Comment: I need 1 more person to approve the edit that fixes this.

Comment: Bless your soul TorelTwiddler.

Answer (score 3):

If the script doesn't raise any errors, this piece of code is most likely returning an empty list.

```
glob.glob("c/Cmos6_*.IG")
```

Seeing as glob.glob works perfectly fine with forward slashes on Windows, the problem is most likely that it's not finding the files, which most likely means that the string you provided has an error somewhere in it. Make sure there isn't any error in `"c/Cmos6_*.IG"`.

If the problem isn't caused by this, then unfortunately, I have no idea why it is happening.

Also, when I tried it, filenames returned by glob.glob have backslashes in them on Windows, so you should probably split by `"\\"` instead.

Comment: I'm happy that you were able to solve it! Also, if you'd like, please consider upvoting or accepting my answer, it would make me very happy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, it looks like a problem of using / in the path.  Windows uses \ instead.

`os.path` contains a number of functions to ease working with paths across platforms.

Comment: That's unlikely, since Python (and most other Unixesque software) accepts / on Windows instead of \.

Comment: @nandhp in this case the \ characters are generated by glob but code looks for /

Answer (score 0):

Your `s.split("/")` should definitely be `s.split(os.pathsep)`.  I got bitten by this, once… :)

In fact, `glob` returns paths with `\` on Windows and `/` on Mac OS X, so you need to do your splitting with the appropriate path separator (`os.pathsep`).